# Custom script font kerning and letter spacing with fontface

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, kerning, letter-spacing

I'm having an issue with a script font called Thirsty Script Bold that I'm using on my site.  The letter spacing appears to be correct for some letters, but not for others.  I haven't even touched the letter spacing though.  You can see an example of it here:
http://oi40.tinypic.com/2wpikgw.jpg.  As you can see, the end of the "e" doesnt fully merge with the "b" and the "b" is too far right to merge with the "s".

I have tried messing with letter spacing, but it just seems to worsen the problem.

Here's my css for the page-

```
p.websites{
font-family: ThirstyScriptBold;
font-size: 80px;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here's my HTML for the page-

```
<p class="websites">Websites</p>
```

Here's my css for fontface-

```
@font-face {font-family: 'ThirstyScriptBold';src: url('ThirstyScriptBold.eot');src: url('ThirstyScriptBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('ThirstyScriptBold.woff') format('woff'),url('ThirstyScriptBold.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

Comment: What about your other styles? Make sure to reset your styling properly: `font-weight: normal;` and `font-style: normal;`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I added the two properties but the problem is still there.

Comment: I solved the problem- turns out there was something wrong with the letter hinting so I re downloaded the web font package from myfonts with the font hinting set to "native" and it works fine now.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately. I believe that is how the font is displayed. I recommend using another font that is similar, but works. You can find one for free at: http://www.google.com/fonts/

Comment: thats what I figured, just wanted to make sure.  I'm pretty annoyed since I payed money for this font.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Right! Sorry I literally just got an account here and I'm still getting used to it!

Comment: you should ask for a refund :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a design flaw in the font, but it may actually depend on lack of kerning. Most browsers do not apply kerning by default, though Firefox does. So you could first try whether adding the following helps:

```
p.websites {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern";
  font-feature-settings: "kern";
}
```

It is also possible that the software used to generate the web font versions destroyed the kerning table; this often happens. I would expect however that the [Webfont package sold by fonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/yellow-design/thirsty-script/bold/buy.html) contains the WOFF, EOT, TTF, and SVG versions with kerning and other OpenType features properly included.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using the Thirsty Script web font. The foundry (Yellow Design Studio) stripped of all the OpenType features from the web fonts. This seems to have removed the kerning data.

> "All OpenType features and all extended glyphs have been removed."

I solved the issue by using the [Font Squirrel web font generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to make a new set of web fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you define an incorrect behavior, what you really need to do is notify the author (or vendor) of the font about the problem. On first, after fixing, you'll have a correct version of the font. On second, this will help other users of this font avoid the same problem in a future.